# From a representation of an array to the array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

A really php newbie here, sorry if the question is too simple.

I’m following an online course and I’ve just got stuck with the arrays chapter.

They show the following representation  of an array:

```
$years
: array = 
  0: array = 
    0: string = 6465
    1: string = 1964-1965
  1: array = 
    0: string = 6566
    1: string = 1965-1966
  2: array = 
    0: string = 6667
    1: string = 1966-1967
  3: array = 
    0: string = 6768
    1: string = 1967-1968
```

And I don’t know how to translate it into a proper PHP array.

Could you please show me how the array would be?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$years = array(
    array( "6465", "1964-1965" ),
    array( "6566", "1965-1966" ),
    ...
);
```

etc

Comment: No problem @MartinShaw if you think my answer helped would you mind marking it as the accepted answer please?

Comment: and it is a multidimensional array? isn't it?

Comment: it's an array of arrays, so yes

Answer (score 1):

[Gabriel Baker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227139/417562) is absolutely correct. Just as an additional point, from PHP 5.4 onwards, there is an alternative, abbreviated array syntax:

```
$years = [
    ['6465', '1964-1965'],
    ['6566', '1965-1966'],
    ['6667', '1966-1967'],
    ['6768', '1967-1968']
];
```

Note that this will not work in previous versions of PHP, but it is clearly much more comprehensible and clear.

Array syntax is documented in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: and this answer is nice to follow as you'll then understand the Javascript notation at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,

```
$years = array( 
  0 => array( 
    0 => 6465,
    1 => 1964-1965,
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => 6566,
    1 => 1965-1966,
  ),
  2 => array( 
    0 => 6667,
    1 => 1966-1967,
  ),
  3 => array( 
    0 => 6768,
    1 => 1967-1968,
  ),
)
```